# Dificuldade Função Menu Sidebar JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com uma dificuldade onde o código que fiz até o momento não está agindo da maneira que eu preciso. O fato é que após a *class* do sub-menu ser ativada, o menu não minimiza. Ou seja, após ser ativado, ele fica maximizado até que eu selecione um outro `menu li`.

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão, talvez seja um erro besta. Abaixo segue o código:

```js
     var handleNav = function() {
             var page  = $('#page-container');
             var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
             var allLinks = $('.sidebar-nav a', sidebar);
             var menuLinks = $('.sidebar-nav-menu', sidebar);
             var submenuLinks = $('.sidebar-nav-submenu', sidebar);
            
             allLinks.on('click', function(e) {
              var link = $(this),
               ripple, d, x, y;
            
              sidebar.find('.sidebar-nav-ripple').removeClass('animate');
            
              if (link.children('.sidebar-nav-ripple').length === 0) {
               link.prepend('<span class="sidebar-nav-ripple"></span>');
              }
            
              var ripple = link.children('.sidebar-nav-ripple');
            
              if (!ripple.height() && !ripple.width()) {
               d = Math.max(link.outerWidth(), link.outerHeight());
               ripple.css({
                height: d,
                width: d
               });
              }
            
              x = e.pageX - link.offset().left - ripple.width() / 2;
              y = e.pageY - link.offset().top - ripple.height() / 2;
            
              ripple.css({
               top: y + 'px',
               left: x + 'px'
              }).addClass('animate');
             });
             menuLinks.on('click', function(e) {
              var link = $(this);
              var windowW = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            
              if (page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini') && (windowW > 991)) {
               if (link.hasClass('open')) {
                link.removeClass('open');
               } else {
                $('#sidebar .sidebar-nav-menu.open').removeClass('open');
                link.addClass('open');
               }
              } else if (!link.parent().hasClass('active')) {
               if (link.hasClass('open')) {
                link.removeClass('open');
               } else {
                $('#sidebar .sidebar-nav-menu.open').removeClass('open');
                link.addClass('open');
               }
            
               setTimeout(resizePageContent, 50);
              }
            
              return false;
             });
            
             submenuLinks.on('click', function(e) {
              var link = $(this);
            
              if (link.parent().hasClass('active') !== true) {
               if (link.hasClass('open')) {
                link.removeClass('open');
               } else {
                link.closest('ul').find('.sidebar-nav-submenu.open').removeClass('open');
                link.addClass('open');
               }
            
               setTimeout(resizePageContent, 50);
              }
            
              return false;
             });
            };
            var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            
            $(".sidebar-nav li a").each(function() {
             if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '') {
              $(this).addClass(" active");
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass(" active");
              $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().addClass(" active");
             }
            });
```

```css
    .sidebar-nav {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 0
    }
    
    
    .sidebar-separator i {
        opacity: .1
    }
    
    #sidebar-toggle-mini {
        display: none
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav-ripple {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(92, 205, 222, .3);
        border-radius: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav-ripple.animate {
        -webkit-animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
        animation: ripple 1s ease-out
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes ripple {
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(3)
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes ripple {
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(3);
            transform: scale(3)
        }
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a {
        display: block;
        color: #8da4bb;
        padding: 0 10px;
        min-height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a.active,
    .sidebar-nav a.open,
    .sidebar-nav a:focus,
    .sidebar-nav a:hover,
    .sidebar-nav li.active>a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a.open,
    .sidebar-nav li.active>a {
        background: #25313e;
        border-right: 4px solid #3180FF
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li>ul li a {
        font-size: 13px
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav li>ul li a.active {
        background: 0 0;
        color: #fff;
        border-right: none
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a.active {
        background: #25313e;
        color: #fff;
        border-right: 4px solid #3180FF
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a>.sidebar-nav-icon {
        margin-right: 10px
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a>.sidebar-nav-icon,
    .sidebar-nav a>.sidebar-nav-indicator {
        display: inline-block;
        opacity: .5;
        width: 18px;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav a>.sidebar-nav-indicator {
        float: right;
        line-height: inherit;
        margin-left: 4px;
        font-size: 10px;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
        transition: transform .15s ease-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden
    }
    
    
    .sidebar-nav a.active>.sidebar-nav-indicator,
    .sidebar-nav a.open>.sidebar-nav-indicator,
    .sidebar-nav li.active>a>.sidebar-nav-indicator {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) rotateZ(0);
        transform: rotate(-90deg) rotateZ(0)
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul {
        display: none;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-out;
        transition: background .25s ease-out
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav .active>ul,
    .sidebar-nav .open+ul {
        display: block;
        background: #25313e
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul a {
        margin: 0 0 0 19px;
        padding-left: 19px;
        border-left: 1px solid #454e59;
        min-height: 34px;
        line-height: 34px;
        font-weight: 400
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul a.open,
    .sidebar-nav ul li.active>a {
        background: 0 0
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul li:before {
        background: #454e59;
        bottom: auto;
        content: "";
        height: 7px;
        left: 16px;
        margin-top: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        right: auto;
        width: 7px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 50%
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width:992px) {
        #page-container.sidebar-visible-lg-mini #sidebar .sidebar-content .sidebar-nav ul li:before {
            display: none
        }
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul ul {
        margin: 0 0 0 19px
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul ul a {
        margin: 0;
        padding-left: 19px;
        font-size: 13px;
        min-height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px
    }
    
    .sidebar-nav ul .active>ul,
    .sidebar-nav ul .open+ul {
        background-color: #454e59
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-container" class="header-fixed-top">
            <div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="gi gi-compass sidebar-nav-icon"></i>
                        <span class="sidebar-nav-mini-hide">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="inddex.html">
                        <i class="gi gi-compass sidebar-nav-icon"></i>
                        <span class="sidebar-nav-mini-hide">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidebar-separator">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="sidebar-nav-menu">
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left sidebar-nav-indicator sidebar-nav-mini-hide"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-cog sidebar-nav-icon"></i>
                        <span class="sidebar-nav-mini-hide">Dropdown</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Link #1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Link #2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Faltou adicionar o CSS.

Comment: Perdão, Corrigi a falta do Css!

Comment: Faltou colocar onde estão declaradas as variáveis `menuLinks` e `submenuLinks`, além de ter uma `};` perdida no meio do código, antes de `var pgurl...`

Comment: sim, novamente peço desculpa, pois não havia adicionado o Cabeçalho, creio que agora esteja tudo correto

Comment: Creio que ainda esteja errado. De onde vem a variável `sidebar`?

Comment: rsrs, poderia me informar se agora falta mais algo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87504/discussion-between-sam-and-leandro-pires).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que precisa é remover a classe `.active` dos elementos ao clicar no Dropdown. Essa classe impede que o Dropdown seja fechado.

Para isso falta um `else` no `if` dentro do evento `menuLinks.on('click'...`:

```
...
else{
   link.removeClass("active");
   link.parent().removeClass("active");
}
```

Ficando assim:

```
menuLinks.on('click', function(e){
   var link = $(this);
   var windowW = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

   if (page.hasClass('sidebar-visible-lg-mini') && (windowW > 991)) {
   console.log("dvd1");
      if (link.hasClass('open')) {
         link.removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
         $('#sidebar .sidebar-nav-menu.open').removeClass('open');
         link.addClass('open');
      }
   }
   else if (!link.parent().hasClass('active')) {
      if (link.hasClass('open')) {
         link.removeClass('open');
      }
      else {
         $('#sidebar .sidebar-nav-menu.open').removeClass('open');
         link.addClass('open');
      }

      setTimeout(resizePageContent, 50);
   }
   // AQUI!
   else{
      link.removeClass("active");
      link.parent().removeClass("active");
   }

   return false;
});
```

Ao clicar no "Dropdown", irá remover a classe `.active` do link e da `<li>`.